# Xpath, find postion of a node inside html code

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to figure out how or if it's possible to figure out what position a html element with a certain content inside a table have.

So here is my html table and I try to get the postion of "Sally", which is obviously position 3 in this case. I tried a lot of xpath queries but nothing outputs the position as a number like "3". The position of "Sally" can of course change.

```
<table class"table" id="t1">
<tbody id="tb1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="sh-osd">
            <a class="osd-link" href="#"><span>Peter</span></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="sh-osd">
            <a class="osd-link" href="#"><span>Jeff</span></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="sh-osd">
            <a class="osd-link" href="#"><span>Sally</span></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="sh-osd">
            <a class="osd-link" href="#"><span>John</span></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So is there maybe a xpath function/query that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using xpath 1.0

```
count(//table/tbody/tr[td/div/a/span/text()='Sally']/preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

try this if using xpath 2.0

```
index-of(//table[@id='t1']/tbody[@id='tb1']/tr/td/div/a/span, //table[@id='t1']/tbody[@id='tb1']/tr/td/div/a/span[text()='Sally'])
```

Comment: I want to get the dynamic position and not the static content/text of the third dom element of my choice ;)

Comment: The count function give me always "1" as a result and with the "index-of" I get an syntax error. Trying to figure the syntax error out.

Comment: @Kuba of course you can just use a variable instead of the actual `Sally` in the query

Comment: I added for xpath 1.0

Comment: oh, thats great. im using freeformater.com, support both xpath 1.0 and 2.0

Comment: Just need to figure out why I get an syntax error in my chrome console ;)

Comment: Do you maybe know why this give me an sytax error in the chrome console?
`$x("index-of(//table/tbody[@id='tb1']/tr/td/div/a/span, //table/tbody[@id='tb1']/tr/td/div/a/span[text()='Sally'])")`

Comment: try $(), this one is ok because we are expecting 1 result

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI':`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an method available. But maybe you can workaround it this way:

```
<?php

$file = "xpath.html";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//a[@class='osd-link']");

$i = 0;

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo $i. " ".$node->nodeValue. "\n";
        $i++;
    }
}

?>
```